# Cannot redirect to custom front page

Tags: php, production-environment, production, elgg

On my local host machine, everything's perfect, but on production server, I cannot override the front default page, that is the custom index, with one I created, instead I always get redirected to /activity.

start.php

```
elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('index', 'system', 'custom_index', 0);

function custom_index($hook, $type, $return, $params) {
    if ($return == true) {
        // another hook has already replaced the front page
        return $return;
    }

    if (!include_once("/pages/rev_index.php")) {
        return false;
    }

    // return true to signify that we have handled the front page
    return true;
}
```

I only get reffered to http://domain-name.com/activity instead of http://domain-name.com/

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file (if using apache) or any redirects (if nginx)?

Comment: Yes I have .htaccess in /public_html @Joey Ciechanowicz

Comment: Whats in the `.htaccess`? Any URL rewrites?

Comment: Yes, there are URL rewrites. It is the default elgg .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with default paths configuration on your server. Using the absolute path, ie. include_once(**DIR** . "/pages/rev_index.php") made it work:

start.php

```
elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('index', 'system', 'custom_index', 0);

function custom_index($hook, $type, $return, $params) {
    if ($return == true) {
        // another hook has already replaced the front page
        return $return;
    }

    if (!include_once(__DIR__ . "/pages/rev_index.php")) {
        return false;
    }

    // return true to signify that we have handled the front page
    return true;
}
```